# Graph formula references error

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I am trying to create a graph with the help of Name Manage. I have come up with the following formula to create the series of numbers required by me. The formula is:

```
Sheet2!B4:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4,Sheet3!AM11,4,,"Sheet2"))
```

When I input this formula into the cell it works properly and provide me with required series, but when I create the name(using name manager) of the series with the same formula and try the create the graph the excel throws the following error:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Can you supply enough data for us to reproduce this?

Comment: I have recreate a similar worksheet.
You can view it from the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1siEdsy0M6MLDVoqZR6JCJaKtsQZ_a-oJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

thing one: you are using relative cell references in the named formula. That means that wherever the active cell is, the named formula will recalculate based on the current cell. `B4` will change to any cell based on the current cell.  Use absolute references like `$B$4`if you want to anchor a certain cell as a base reference.

Thing two: Indirect with a complicated nesting of functions that reveal a row and/or column can be replaced by a more efficient Index formula.

Thing one is probably the thing that causes your problems, because the result of the formula will change with the selected cell.

**Edit after inspecting the workbook**

The problem is definitely the relative cell references, and making them absolute definitely solves the problem. Your formula was defined with the active cell in B10 and it is

```
=Sheet1!B1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,Sheet1!D10,4))
```

But when the active cell is in A1, for example, the formula changes to

```
=Sheet1!A1048568:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,Sheet1!C1,4))
```

Every time you click on a cell, the named formula will recalculate based on the position of the current cell. That's why you need absolute references. You can correct your formula to

```
=Sheet1!$B$1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,Sheet1!$D$10,4))
```

Or you can use Index instead of Indirect this way:

```
=Sheet1!$B$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1,Sheet1!$D$10)
```

Or you can use a simple Offset function

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,0,0,1,Sheet1!$D$10-1)
```

Whichever formula you prefer, this will always deliver the correct range, no matter which cell is the active cell.

Once you have the date range in place, you can use a simple offset from the date range to get the series ranges.

Offset by one row for Open, offset by two rows for High, etc.

```
=OFFSET(Date,1,0)
```

The screenshot shows the Date formula with the Offset function and you can see the formulas used for the Open, High, Low, and AdjClose names. The chart shows the series Open and AdjClose. Note how the marching ants highlight the current extent of the named range. The Date name will always refer to a range starting in B1 because that cell is anchored with an absolute reference.

[image]

If you have any questions about that, pipe up.

Comment: Firstly, absolute reference also doesn't help.
Secondly, can you provide with the index formula for the same.
Finally, I want that my result formula changes with the change in the selected cell.

Comment: Well, absolute references will help. I have added some more explanations after looking at your sample file.

Comment: I am still able to get it right, can you please share the sheet. It might help.

And secondly, what does it Sheet1!A1048568 means.

Comment: Can it be that you mean that you are NOT able to get it right? Please, just follow instructions. You seem to have an issue with details. Details matter. `Sheet1!A1048568` is a cell address near the very bottom of the sheet in row 1048568. That's what you get when you use relative cell references. I have given you the formulas you need according to the data layout of your Google sheet. If you can't copy and paste these formulas, I don't know how else to help you. My screenshot shows that the approach works in **Excel**. If you are not using Excel, then you may need a different approach.

Comment: Also "doesn't help" and don't "get it right" does not help much. You need to detail exactly what you have done, because there are many ways where things can go wrong. Do you understand the difference between absolute and relative cell references? Do you know how to reference a range name in a chart? Are you aware that it's a bit more complex than just using the range name in the series value box? If not, then you may need to do some more learning before you can apply the approach. It's not my solution that's at fault. My screenshot shows that it works.